# Open form in a model window

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I have this code that opens a form from an image button and I want the form to open modally.

```
<a class="ms-addnew" id="idHomePageNewItem" href="https://thisCompany.com/HR/PerfRev/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=8&amp;ListId={8C0AC114-B19A-4CF7-B353-FC47A95E3D23}&amp;RootFolder=" onclick="javascript:NewItem2(event, 'https://thisCompany.com/HR/PerfRev/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=8&amp;ListId={8C0AC114-B19A-4CF7-B353-FC47A95E3D23}&amp;RootFolder=');return false;" target="_self">
<img src="../Images1/PGAT_Add_New.png" alt="AddNew" style="border-style: none; border-color: inherit; border-width: medium; float: left; width: 175px; height: 31px" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#idHomePageNewItem').click(function(){
    var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
    options.url = $(this).attr('href');
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
});
```

Use above function. Or change html as

```
<a class="ms-addnew" id="idHomePageNewItem" href="#" onclick="javascript:var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();options.url = 'https://thisCompany.com/HR/PerfRev/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=8&amp;ListId={8C0AC114-B19A-4CF7-B353-FC47A95E3D23}&amp;RootFolder=';SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);" target="_self">
<img src="../Images1/PGAT_Add_New.png" alt="AddNew" style="border-style: none; border-color: inherit; border-width: medium; float: left; width: 175px; height: 31px" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open forms in a modal dialog by using [SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff410058(v=office.14).aspx).

Here is the example code given from the site as well:

```
//Using the DialogOptions class.
var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();

options.title = "My Dialog Title";
options.width = 400;
options.height = 600;
options.url = "/_layouts/DialogPage.aspx";

SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);

//Using a generic object.
var options = {
    title: "My Dialog Title",
    width: 400,
    height: 600,
    url: "/_layouts/DialogPage.aspx" };

SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
```

You essentially just need to give it the url and can play with the other options as needed.